# I have some problems with a coin toss program

Tags: java, coin-flipping

I am pretty new to java and using codehs, i need to find the amount and percentage of heads/ tails in a 100 toss program. I've got the 100 flips down but the percentage and printing the amount are beyond me, here is my code and thanks for the help

```
public class CoinFlips extends ConsoleProgram
{
    public void run()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if (Randomizer.nextBoolean())
        {
            System.out.println("Heads");
        }
        else
        {
        System.out.println("Tails");
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since it's out of 100, simply keep track of the count of both and you're done.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils the count of one should be sufficient. The count of the other is always 100 - count.

Comment: I'd prefer to count the head and tails, rather than heads and total. The former seems more symmetrical to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

Add:

```
int headCount = 0;
int tailsCount = 0;
```

You can use them by:

```
        if (Randomizer.nextBoolean())
    {
        System.out.println("Heads");
        headsCount++;
    }
    else
    {
    System.out.println("Tails");
        tailsCount++;
    }
```

Then write a method to calculate the percentage. Since this looks like a homework assignment, I'll leave that to you.

Answer (score 1):

## Problem:

You will need a counter and a variable for the result.

## Solution

```
int TOTAL =100;
int counter =0;
for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL; i++) {
if (Randomizer.nextBoolean()) {
    System.out.println("Heads");
    counter++;
}else{
    System.out.println("Tails");
}

    double procent = (double)counter/TOTAL*100;
    System.out.println("From "+ TOTAL +" flipped coins " + procent+"% were Heads" );
}
```

Comment: I don't see the need for an array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store how many times there had been **Heads** and how many times **Tails**: you need a variable to store the **Heads** and incremeht the variable every time it turns to **HEADS**. Then after the loop the number in this variable will be the number of **HEADS** tosses. Tails is 100-heads. For example:

```
public class CoinFlips extends ConsoleProgram
{
    public void run()
    {
        int heads = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            if (Randomizer.nextBoolean())
            {
                heads++;
                System.out.println("Heads");
            }
            else
            {
                 System.out.println("Tails");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Percentage of Heads = " + heads + "%");
        System.out.println("Percentage of Tails = " + (100 - heads) + "%");
    }
}
```

Since the amount of coint tosses is 100, the amount of the HEADS tosses equals the percentage of HEADS tosses, that is why you can output the actual value of the variable.

Comment: That's the amount not the percentage.

Comment: Yes, but out of 100 tosses the amount equals the percentage.

Comment: So add a percent symbol at the end.

Answer (score 0):

public class CoinFlips extends ConsoleProgram
{

```
public void run()
{
 int headsCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if (Randomizer.nextBoolean())
        {
            System.out.println("Heads");
            headsCount++;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Tails");
        }
    }
    float headsPercentage = headsCount/100f;
    System.out.println("Heads percentage: " + headsPercentage.toString());
}


}
```

This should work